# winapi - Date time picker, change size of prev/next button

Tags: c++, winapi, button, datepicker, size

I have this code:

```
HWND hwndDP = CreateWindowEx(0,
     DATETIMEPICK_CLASS,
     TEXT("DateTime"),
     WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
     20, 50, 400, 60,
     hDlg,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL);                     
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(40, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, L"Arial");
SendMessage(hwndDP, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hFont), TRUE);
```

which creates date time picker like in image below. AS you can see, I change the size of font, so the font of date time picker is bigger. I have problem, that buttons which are circled (next/prev month) don't change the size and are small. Is it possible to change the size of this buttons. I need it because I use this date time picker on monitor with touch and is hard to click on this two buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to change this that I can see. Those controls aren't actually real buttons - they're just drawn on the window, and the calendar control bases the size of them on the value of `NONCLIENTMETRICS.iScrollHeight` - it doesn't let you change them.

The only way to change this is globally which would affect all scrollbars in the system, probably not something you want to do.

One idea I have for you would be to sub-class the control to put your own (real) button controls over the top of the existing ones.

Then, when your sub-class procedure gets the `WM_COMMAND` message to say they've been clicked, send the calendar control a `WM_KEYDOWN` message for `VK_NEXT` or `VK_PRIOR` - those keys will cause it to scroll a month in either direction.

Comment: really interesting idea. But is it possible to have buttons, which are not visible but when click somebody on it (but is not visible), than sends WM_COMMAND? I have idea to create something like regions on certain position and if somebody click on this region, than move next or back. But is simplier way than regions?

Comment: @JaroKollár You could use a sub-class to catch mouse clicks in the areas without a button but there'd be no visible indication that you could click there. I guess theoretically you could actually draw your own button in a sub-class that handles `WM_PAINT` and `WM_PRINTCLIENT`. You'd need to experiment though and see how well the various ideas work.

Comment: So I tried it, but I don't know why, when I click on the arrow which shows date picker, than I catch WM_LBUTTONDOWN, but when I'm clicking on showed date time picker, no WM_LBUTTONDOWN comes. So how Can I catch the click? I think that problem is that I sub class only the control with showed date and button which show date picker, but is not subclassed the date picker. How can I get handle to it to subclass it?

Comment: @JaroKollár *To retrieve a handle to the month-calendar control, send the DTP control a DTM_GETMONTHCAL message*

Comment: This works, thanks. For another people, need to call DTM_GETMONTHCALL after DTN_DROPDOWN notification.